# How to use UpdatePanel with TabContainer and FileUpload?

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload, ajaxcontroltoolkit, tabcontrol

I have 2 tabs inside an `UpdatePanel` and a button inside `Tab2`

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upd" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>

<asp:TabContainer ID="tab" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true">
    <asp:TabPanel HeaderText="Tab1" runat="server">
    </asp:TabPanel>
    <asp:TabPanel HeaderText="Tab2" runat="server">

        <asp:LinkButton ID="btn" runat="server" />

    </asp:TabPanel>
</asp:TabContainer>

    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

I want the tabs to change without reloading the entire page, so the `UpdatePanel` works fine. But on the second tab I have a file upload and the button `btn` is supposed to submit this file.

How can I do a **full postback when clicking `btn`** keeping a partial postback when changing tabs?

Comment: Something like this?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2094579/how-to-make-updatepanel-ignore-clicking-one-button-which-is-inside-it

Comment: @Marc yes, but since the button is inside the `TabPanel` the trigger can't find the control, and it throws an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can use Response.Redirect to the same page in the OnClick event.

Comment: Redirect? And what about the file? As a workaround I can just remove the updatepanel and live with the full postback...